# How to display only one data with the same id

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, 
                 transactions.trans_id, 
                 date_of_transaction, 
                 company_name 
          FROM suppliers 
          JOIN products ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id
          JOIN transactions ON transactions.trans_id = products.trans_id
```

So this query would select all `supplier_id`, `trans_id` and `date_of_transaction` from the tables that i join and it would display like this.

**[Transaction Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFVRr.png)**

But what i would like to do is that how could i show **ONLY ONE DATA** with the same `trans_id` not like in the picture it displays two transactions with the same `trans_id` please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct.

```
      SELECT distinct suppliers.supplier_id, transactions.trans_id, date_of_transaction, 
      company_name FROM suppliers 
      JOIN products ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id
      JOIN transactions ON transactions.trans_id = products.trans_id"
```